# How to update height and width of the Sitecore progress box

Tags: commands

We have a custom command to sync some items with Sitecore. Sitecore progress box is used to perform the job and at the end we have to display the errors or warnings if any.

Sitecore progress box is showing only a few details and the rest message is getting trimmed and unable to view the full error message or warning, for example,

```
sitecore.shell.applications.dialogs.progressboxes

Method : Progressbox.Execute
```

How to resize the progress box height and width & display all the `error/warning` messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the Sitecore Sheer UI related stuff under this location.

```
wwwroot\yourapplication\sitecore\shell
```

You will find all the UI controls under `XML` files. For example, if you want to update the CSS style of the publish popup then you can find it under this location.

```
wwwroot\yourapplication\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish\publish.xml
```

You will find all the styles of this popup in the XML.

As per your question if you want to resize or change the style of the progress bar then you can find it under this location.

```
wwwroot\yourapplication\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Progress
```

You will find XML and CSS files for the popup.

[image]

You can update them and add them to your `Visual Studio solution`, so it will replace this `XML` with your changes if you publish your site.

Also if you want to search for any `Sitecore` OOTB UI stuff (like other popup or windows) then you can use any third-party notepad tool like `Notepad++` or other and find with any label. It will give you the `XML` file and then you can update it.